# Meaning of DNSEnabledForWINSResolution

Tags: dns, wmic, netbios

I am trying to interpret the results of `wmic nicconfig list full`, and I do not understand the meaning of `DNSEnabledForWINSResolution`.

If I consider the name, I would think that if I try to resolve a name with WINS but fail to do so, then DNS will be tried.

However, according to Microsoft's rather vague documentation (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapterconfiguration), it is the other way around: if a name cannot be resolved with DNS, then WINS will be tried. This sounds less sensible to me but I think the description says this.

So, which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with the Microsoft documentation. That enabling that option will *prefer* DNS over WINS for name resolution.

If that option is disabled then **only** WINS resolution will be enabled. If you are enabling DNS resolution in place of WINS then presumably you have a reason for it and would want DNS to take priority.

The name `DNSEnabledForWINSResolution` doesn't actually state which will happen first, only that it is allowing DNS resolution in place of in addition to WINS.